# disable auto-building of specific directory

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework2

I have eclipse 3.7.2 to work on PHP projects that are on remote Linux servers that can be accessed by SSH.

I installed eclipse RSE (Remote System Explorer) and I used it to add a remote project and configured it as a PHP project.

best practices for Zend Framework 2 projects is to include the used Zend Framework version within the sources of the application, but what happens then is that whenever I reopen eclipse it tries to build the project and validate the entire zend framework directory.

how can I choose that the auto builder will ignore that directory since it's not something that I modify. in general I have no idea why it needs to validate that directory every time and it does not check for md5 on the directory content before trying to validate every time. but it this can't be fixed, i need to ignore the entire zend framework directory foom auto building.

using Eclipse 3.7.2 with PHP plugin.
using Zend Framework 2.0 beta4 with basically the skeleton application and modules that are provided from the zend framework site.

thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that it's possible to do that.

i just need to right click on the directory i want to exclude from auto-building.

then to go to `Build Path` => `Exclude`.

this excludes the directory from auto-building and resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest ZendSkeletonApplication, you'll see in index.php that you can place ZF2 outside of the project as long as you set the `ZF2-PATH` environment variable.

Comment: thank you for that. i still would like to know if it's possible to disable directory from auto building.

Comment: What do you mean by "auto building" ? - UPDATE. Ah - you're talking about Eclipse.  Sorry, I don't use Eclipse, so cannot help with the specifics of the IDE.